# How Proxy object declaration helps in DI?

Tags: magento2

My understanding is Object Manager instantiates objects before there were injected into any other class's Constructor OR whenever new classes use OM's create method. from then on only instances will be given to dependent class's constructors. can you point that spot in code where object manager creates list of all classes objects may be at the bootstrap time ? Please correct . can you point that spot in code.

Assuming that,  when one of some_other_class's _constructor() has  a parameter as slow loading object , how  declaring proxy argument make difference because object manager only providing instance of object at that time of DI ?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy help in two cases:

- on circular dependencies
- on unused dependencies

This work because proxy have only ObjectManger as constructor dependency and proxied object created lazy on first method call.